# Changing the 'flower' image that is shown logging on to Windows 7

Tags: windows, login

Where can I change the 'flower' image that is shown when users are logging on to the domain in Windows Vista and Windows 7?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Account Picture can be changed manually by going to Control Panel > User Accounts. There is an option for "Change your account picture", which will provide pre-made options, or the ability to insert your own image.

You could also try replacing "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\User Account Pictures\user.bmp" with your own 128x128 image on all computers, to replace the default image. However I have not tested this to ensure it will work in all situations.